# ¿Como transformar una columna en Cabecera de Columnas en SQL?

Tags: sql-server

Lo que pasa es que requiero transformar una columna en cabecera de las otras columnas, no se si me explico.

Aqui algo mas detallado:

Tengo esta consulta la cual me muestra la columna de descripcion la cual quisiera que fuera la cabecera de las columnas.

```
select cantidad,Punto1, Punto2,Punto3,Punto4,TallasDetalle.IdTalla,TallasDetalle.Descripcion
From tblProductoPedido join TallasDetalle
on tblProductoPedido.IdTalla = TallasDetalle.IdTalla
where Codigo = '900121220066'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Logre hacer uno muestro la siguiente consulta:

```
Select * From(
 select cantidad,Punto1, Punto2,Punto3,Punto4,TallasDetalle.IdTalla,TallasDetalle.Descripcion
 From tblProductoPedido join TallasDetalle
 on tblProductoPedido.IdTalla = TallasDetalle.IdTalla
 where Codigo = '900121220066') as a Pivot(AVG(Punto1) For [Descripcion] in ([25]))   as TablaPivote
```

y asi se ve:

[image: El punto1 Fue remplazado por '25']

Ahora no se como hacer para que los demas tambien puedan ser remplazados y aparezca por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por Favor si alguien me pudiera ayudar o apoyar se los Agradecería.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas hace uso de `pivot`.
La estructura de un pivote es:

```
`PIVOT (funcionDeAgregado(campoDeAgregado)FOR ColumnaPivote IN (valoresDeColumnaPivote)) AS Alias;`
```

En msdn puedes encontrar ejemplos incluso para hacer pivote dinamico
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/communitydocs/servidores/sql-server/pivot-dinamico)

Comment: Ya he realizado la estructura, porque como puedo realizar varias estructuras dentro de uno mismo.

Answer (score 0):

A tu inquietud seria para brindarte apoyo mostrar la implementacion de un pivot dinamico como enuncio en el siguiente ejemplo:

Teniendo la siguientes tablas de insumo inicial:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la idea es generar un proceso para que en el caso del ejemplo las fechas se conviertan en las columnas de nuestro reporte, para lo cual con el siguiente storeProcedure se generaria la sig. logica:

```
USE [tuEsquema]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[prcPivotDinamic]    Script Date: 6/21/2018 2:32:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prcPivotDinamic]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @fchIni VARCHAR(255),
    @fchFin VARCHAR(255),
    @identificacion VARCHAR(255)    
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @periodos AS NVARCHAR(MAX)  
    DECLARE @PivotDynamicEsp NVARCHAR(MAX)  
    DECLARE @PivotDynamicGnral NVARCHAR(MAX)    
    DECLARE @dropViewGnral NVARCHAR(MAX)    
    DECLARE @dropViewEsp NVARCHAR(MAX)  

    SELECT @periodos = COALESCE(@periodos + ', ', '')+ Quotename(Fecha)
                        FROM 
                        (
                            SELECT DISTINCT Fecha  
                            FROM consultHistoricoEstGnral  
                            WHERE Fecha BETWEEN @fchIni AND @fchFin
                            GROUP BY Fecha
                        ) AS periodos  

        --print 'periodos: '+@periodos;         

         SET @dropViewGnral = 'DROP VIEW MyPivotDynamicGnral'+@identificacion

         --print @dropViewGnral

            if object_id('MyPivotDynamicGnral'+@identificacion,'v') is not null
                EXEC sp_executesql @dropViewGnral

        SET @dropViewEsp = 'DROP VIEW MyPivotDynamicEsp'+@identificacion

            if object_id('MyPivotDynamicEsp'+@identificacion,'v') is not null
                EXEC sp_executesql @dropViewEsp

            SET @PivotDynamicEsp = ' CREATE VIEW MyPivotDynamicEsp'+@identificacion+' AS
            SELECT              
                EstadoEspecifico,
                '+@periodos+'               
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT 
                        CantidadEspecifica,
                        EstadoEspecifico,
                        Fecha
                    FROM consultHistoricoEstEsp
                ) AS SourceTable
            PIVOT
                (
                SUM(CantidadEspecifica)
                FOR Fecha IN ('+@periodos+')
                ) AS PivotTable;
            '
            SET @PivotDynamicGnral = 'CREATE VIEW MyPivotDynamicGnral'+@identificacion+' AS
            SELECT 
                EstadoGeneral,          
                '+@periodos+'               
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT 
                        CantidadGeneral,
                        EstadoGeneral,
                        Fecha
                    FROM consultHistoricoEstGnral
                ) AS SourceTable
            PIVOT
                (
                SUM(CantidadGeneral)
                FOR Fecha IN ('+@periodos+')
                ) AS PivotTable;'

            --print @PivotDynamicGnral

            IF(@periodos <> '')
                BEGIN                   
                    EXEC sp_executesql @PivotDynamicEsp                 
                    EXEC sp_executesql @PivotDynamicGnral
                    print 'done'
                END
            ELSE
                PRINT 'notRow'


END
GO
```

Ahora bien cuando se realiza el call al store procedure el resultante en las views construida es el sig:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En si en el ejemplo muestro como implementar un pivote dinámico basado en lo que son dos tablas de insumo iniciales para unos reportes solicitados. Espero te sea de utilidad este ejemplo de uso e implementación, saludos.